# Named scope and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have freight_requests, trips, and bookings.

A freight_request has_many trips (not all trips belong to a freight_request)

A trip has_many bookings (all bookings belong to a trip)

I'm trying to write a scope for freight_requests that gets all freight_requests that aren't booked. That includes freight_requests that don't have trips, and freight_requests that do have trips but that those trips aren't booked.

At the moment I have

## trip.rb

```
has_many :bookings
scope :not_booked, where("trips.id NOT IN (SELECT trip_id FROM bookings)")
```

## booking.rb

```
belongs_to :trip
```

## freight_request.rb

```
has_many :trips
scope :not_booked, joins(:trips) & Trip.not_booked
scope :no_trip, where("freight_requests.id NOT IN (SELECT freight_request_id FROM trips)")
```

The problem is the no_trip code doesn't return freight_requests that have no trips (it returns nothing).

Anyone got any ideas on how I can do this? Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot the include on a Trip model in :no_trip scope.

`scope :no_trip, includes(:trips).where("freight_requests.id NOT IN (SELECT freight_requests_id FROM trips)")`

I also wanted to note that this query goes through all trip records, which might be expensive if you have a lot of data. Counter cache on a FreightRequest model may be a faster way in which case your :no_trip scope would be:

`scope :no_trip, where(:trips_counter => 0)`